# Is every continuous local martingale a uniform limit of step-processes?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

The following question pertains to Wengenroth's textbook "Wahrscheinlichkeitstheorie", de Gruyter 2008 (in German).

The *covariance* (aka *compensator*) of the continuous local martingales $X, Y \in \mathcal{CM}^{\text{loc}}(\mathcal{F})$ is defined (in Theorem 9.6 on p. 181) as
$$
[X, Y] := XY - X_0Y_0 - X\cdot Y - Y\cdot X
$$
where $X\cdot Y$ is the Itô integral of $X$ w.r.t. the integrator $Y$: $(X \cdot Y)_t = \int_0^t X_s dY_s$, and likewise $Y\cdot X$. However, the Itô integral w.r.t. an integrator that is a local martingale has only been defined (p. 179) when the integrand is in $\overline{T}(\mathcal{F})$, i.e. when the integrand can be uniformly approximated by a step-process, where a step-process is defined (p. 176) as a stochastic process that is adapted to the filtration $\mathcal{F}$, and such that each of its paths is a step-function, i.e. a function of the form $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n \mathbb{1}_{[t_n, t_{n + 1})} = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty a_n(\omega) \mathbb{1}_{[t_n(\omega), t_{n + 1}(\omega))}$, for some sequence of real numbers $a(\omega) = (a_1(\omega), a_2(\omega), \dots)$ and some sequence of non-negative real numbers $(0 = t_0(\omega), t_1(\omega), \dots)$ that increases monotonically (possibly weakly) to infinity: $t_n(\omega) \uparrow \infty$.

So the definition of covariance/compensator, given above, begs the question: is every local martingale in $\overline{T}(\mathcal{F})$? If not, then the definition makes no sense, does it? Or am I missing something?

Comment: What do you mean by "*uniformly* approximated"? Uniformly on compact $t$-sets?

Comment: @saz: I mean approximated in the $|||\cdot|||_\infty$ half-norm, where $|||X|||_\infty := \sup \{|X_t(\omega)| : \omega \in \Omega, t \in [0, \infty)\}$ [Wengenroth, p. 176].

Comment: Okay. The point is actually that $X$ and $Y$ are processes with *continuous* sample paths and this implies that we can approximate them uniformly with step functions. (It is very important that in your definition of step functions the partition $0=t_0(\omega)< t_1(\omega)<\ldots$ may depend on $\omega$; otherwise we are doomed.)

Comment: @saz: But how can we construct uniformly approximating step-processes that are adapted to the filtration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $\epsilon>0$. Define iteratively a sequence of stopping times by

$$\tau_n := \inf\{t>\tau_{n-1}; |X(t)-X(\tau_{n-1})| \geq \epsilon\}, \qquad n \in \mathbb{N},$$

$\tau_0 := 0$. Then

$$f(t,\omega) := \sum_{n \geq 1} X_{\tau_{n-1}}(\omega) 1_{[\tau_{n-1}(\omega),\tau_n(\omega))}(t)$$

satisfies $\|X-f\|_{\infty} \leq \epsilon$ (since $X$ has continuous sample paths) and $f$ is adapted.

Comment: I think your stopping times should be defined as follows $\tau_0 := 0$, $\tau_{n + 1} := (\tau_n + 1) \wedge \inf \{t \geq \tau_n \mid: |X_t - X_{\tau_n}| \geq \varepsilon\} = (\tau_n + 1) \wedge \inf \{t \geq 0 \mid: |X_t - X^{\tau_n}_t| \geq \varepsilon\}$ (instead of $1$ I could have used any positive constant). This modification endows the stopping times $\tau_i$ with the following three characteristics, which they lack in your current answer.

Comment: 1) The $\tau_i$'s are real-valued, so that it makes sense to write $X_{\tau_i}$, 2) $\tau_{i + 1} > \tau_i$, so it makes sense to write $\mathbb{1}_{\left[\tau_{i - 1}(\omega), \tau_i(\omega)\right)}$. (Also, it makes sure the stopping times increase to infinity, which is a nice, albeit not necessary, touch.),

Comment: 3) The $\tau_i$'s are stopping times: indeed, according to theorem 7.10.2, "Entrance Times", in Wengenroth's textbook (p. 139), if $Y = (Y_t)_{t \in [0, \infty)}$ is a continuous stochastic process and if $B$ is a closed set of real numbers, then $\rho := \inf \{t \geq 0 \mid: Y_t \in B\}$ is a stopping time w.r.t. the natural filtration generated by $Y$.

Comment: I would also like to point out that the continuity of $X$ is not needed in the place where you mentioned it explicitly in your answer; rather it is needed in order to ensure that the $\tau_i$'s are stopping times. Finally, I'd like to note that nowhere in your answer is the fact that $X$ is a local martingale used, so that your answer actually applies to a larger class of processes $X$, namely continuous, real-valued stochastic processes defined over the time interval $[0, \infty)$. It is not even required that $X$ be adapted to any filtration.

Comment: @EvanAad Yeah, sorry, I wanted to define them inductively, i.e. $\tau_n := \inf\{t> \tau_{n-1}; \dots\}$ (I fixed it). However, there is no need for $\tau_{n+1}$ to be bounded,if $\tau_{n+1}(\omega) = \infty$, then $$f(t,\omega) = \sum_{j=1}^{n} X_{\tau_{j-1}}(\omega) 1_{[\tau_{j-1}(\omega),\tau_j(\omega))}(t)$$ is well-defined (there is no $X_{\tau_n}(\omega)$ needed). Concerning your last remark: The continuity **is** needed to ensure that $\|X-f\|_{\infty} \leq \epsilon$. If $X$ is not continuous (i.e. cadlag), then this estimate does not hold true.

Comment: @EvanAad It doesn't really matter since we can use the completed (right-continuous) filtration instead; but you are right, it makes more sense to use $\geq \epsilon$. Thanks for your comments.